# Segment a region from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

After some processing of a image I, extracted some region of a image.
[Here is the .npy file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AGWv1LBY5re31-kCaOJ4HCyZVmm2W9c5/view?usp=sharing)

```
segmented_image = np.load('data.npy')
plt.imshow(segmented_image)
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to `crop/segment` the region of P. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try to find min/max x/y values for the color pic, and then crop the image to this values

Comment: @kabooya yes, but I am trying to segment in a unsupervised way, like area calculating or shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try contour filtration.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.load("data.npy")
cv2.imshow("image", image)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("threshold_image", threshold_image)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# here you can apply your conter filter logic
# In this image I can see biggest contur is "p"
selected_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

mask_image = np.zeros_like(threshold_image)
cv2.drawContours(mask_image, [selected_contour], -1, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow("mask_image", mask_image)

segmented_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_image)
cv2.imshow("segmented_image", segmented_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: process images]